# Vue 3 (compsition API) remove all ref from list of objects with ref (unref deep)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Is there any simple way (without creating custom helpers) to unref(arr) where arr contains objects with ref, computed and other reactive properties?

A simple way is just to iterate the list and the iterate the propries of each object... but there must be a more simple way then this? Im looking for something like

> const arr = ref([])

> //some code that will fill the arr with objs. props can be ref(someting) or computed
>
> cost req = unref(arr, deep: true)
>
> await api.post(req)

anyone have done this in good way?

/J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question, so I made: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-deepunref

Answer (score 3):

[toRaw](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#toraw) - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: wont recursively unref props in array of object containing refs or similar. answer above works perf tho :)

Comment: Link moved to _advanced reactivity_ https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw